# Reaching a Docker environment running in VMware from LAN

Tags: docker, networking, ubuntu, vmware

Here is my setup:

I have a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS machine running in VMware (vSphere client).

On this machine, I have a local Drupal website running in Docker using Wodby Docker4Drupal https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal

The website can be accessed on the Ubuntu machine on http://drupal.localhost:8000.

The Ubuntu machine has an IP of **192.168.10.100** which I can ping from my local Windows machine which is on the same LAN (Windows computer IP address is 192.168.10.97).

Is there any way that I could access the Drupal website directly from the browser on a computer that is on the same LAN (ie. my Windows machine)?

I have tried to access http://192.168.10.100:8000 but I get a `404 page not found` message. On port `80` I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Any idea?

I shall also mention that on the Ubuntu VM, I also get *the same* `404 page not found` if I try to reach http://0.0.0.0:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000. Only the hostname configured within the project resolves to the Drupal website (http://drupal.localhost:8000).

---

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` I am using.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - d4d-db-data:/var/lib/mysql # Use bind mount

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached

  crond:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_crond"
    environment:
      CRONTAB: "0 * * * * drush -r /var/www/html/web cron"
    command: sudo -E LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so crond -f -d 0
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached

  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
    - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    #      NGINX_DRUPAL_FILE_PROXY_URL: http://example.com
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.rule=Host(`mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
    - '8000:80'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

volumes:
  d4d-db-data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was only a setting in Traefik. I had to add a second router http rule for the nginx container in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx_lan.rule=Host(`192.168.10.100`)"
```

So the full nginx section now looks like that:

```
  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
    - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/web
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: $NGINX_VHOST_PRESET
    #      NGINX_DRUPAL_FILE_PROXY_URL: http://example.com
    volumes:
    - ./web:/var/www/html:cached
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx_lan.rule=Host(`192.168.10.100`)"
```

It works fine. I can now access my Drupal website at http://192.168.10.100:8000 from any other device on the same LAN.

In my case, `PROJECT_BASE_URL` and `PROJECT_NAME` are configured in an `.env` file and correspond to `drupal.localhost` and `drupal` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the docker-compose file from that github repo it's using traefik and should correctly expose port 8000, that should default to 0.0.0.0:8000.
Maybe Ubuntu firewall is blocking incoming TCP port 8000. That could explain why it works on drupal.localhost:8000 which most likely resolves to 127.0.0.1 but not from 192.* LAN.

Check Ubuntu firewall:

`$ sudo ufw status`

Make sure incoming TCP 8000 is allowed from anywhere, or at least for your LAN ip range.
If not, you can open it with:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from any to any port 8000 proto tcp
```

Comment: `sudo ufw status` returns `Status: inactive`.

Comment: I shall also mention that indeed, I am using Traefik with the default ports configuration: `'8000:80'` and that I also get *the same* `404 page not found` when I try to open http://0.0.0.0:8000 or http://localhost:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000. I can only reach the website by using the hostname that I have configured in the project (http://drupal.localhost:8000).

Comment: have you tried adding this to your DNS:

```192.168.10.100 Drupal.localhost```

If you don't have a DNS server on your LAN you can add it to the host file on a client you're using. For linux it's ```/etc/hosts``` and windows it's probably ```C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts```

Comment: uhmm... why would I do that? I am not trying to access `Drupal.localhost` from the distant machine, only the IP.

Comment: "Is there any way that I could access the Drupal website directly from the browser on a computer that is on the same LAN (ie. my Windows machine)?" sounded exactly like that but hey, glad it works! Check https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule for more information on Host Headers.